# Add values to table1 for each element from table2 and using MAX(id) + 1 from table1 as table2 id

Tags: mysql, max

I have `table1` and `table2` and want to do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, OWNER_ID, NAME) SELECT (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table1) + 1, ID, 'value' FROM table2
```

The query above does not work and returns:

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.table1(ID)"; SQL statement:
```

Any help please?

`table1`:

```
| ID | OWNER_ID | NAME |
| --- | ---- | --- |
```

`ŧable2`:

```
| ID | OWNER_ID_REF | NAME |
| --- | ---- | --- |
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share your `show create table` statement results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @i:=(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table1);
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, OWNER_ID, NAME) SELECT @i:=@i+1, ID, 'value' FROM table2
```

try this query it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ID` is a primary key column in `table1`.  Your current insert will most likely be inserting the same `ID` value multiple times, because the max subquery will have the same value for each record in `table2`.  Assuming `ID` is auto increment, you probably should not be assigning a value to it anyway.  Here is one option:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (OWNER_ID, NAME)
SELECT ID, 'value'
FROM table2;
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives `NULL not allowed for column "ID"`

Comment: To ask a second time, please include your `CREATE TABLE` statements.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1` etc.  I suspect poor table design here.

Comment: @Briston12 please alter your table to set `id` field as auto increment

Answer (score 0):

You are using 
**SELECT (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table1) + 1, ID, 'value' FROM table2**

When you are inserting  Through select
Max(ID)+1 
give sample value all the records for table2

Use something like this...

Create table #tt( id int primary key ,Name varchar(200))

declare @vaue int = (select max(id) from #tt)

insert into #tt
select row_number() over(order by id) + @vaue
,Name from #tt